# Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

while adding Firebase database dependency in the file I am having these errors:

[image]

Gradle file code is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mymate.myownidea.fawad.my_mate"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

And remove this line of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

Don't also forget to add in your top level `build.gradle` file the latest version of Google Play Services:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Please see [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services) more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things:

Update `com.google.gms:google-services` from `3.1.1` to `3.2.0`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}
```

Change `compile` to `implementation`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```